# How to delete more than one header in an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, header, rows

I have an array 68x68. This is an output of a model and I have this array repeated 1461 times in a data document but with a header 1461 times:

```
LINE1 (header)-->     1    1   1.000000E+00   1.000000E+00             HEAD    68    68 (...)      
LINE2 (array)--> -2.00000E+20  1.68700E+01

LINE70 (header 2)   1    1   1.000000E+00   1.000000E+00             HEAD    68    68 (...)  
LINE 3 (array)--> -2.00000E+20  1.68700E+01

...

LINE 302427
```

I need to operate with the array but I don't know how to delete all the headers, I've been trying with `loadtxt('mydata', skiprow=1)` but I only know how to skip the first line...

Does anybody know how to delete all the headers and achieving a regular array?

Comment: What kind of document are you reading. What is `loadtxt()`?

Comment: I'm reading a .dat file and loadtxt is the function I use to load the data. It is a numpy function. Thanks.